# Unable to create a Browser() instance with Splinter

Tags: python, splinter

I'm following the splinter [documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l0pMP.png) , which explicitily says :

First of all, import Browser class and instantiate it.

```
from splinter import Browser
browser = Browser()
```

I have done the same thing on differnt environments and different files, but I always get the following :

[image]

I installed [image] (splinter 0.18.1).

This seems to be quite basic, what am I missing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution

Splinter is a wrapper designed on top of selenium and other automation web tools.

The reason I got this error was because I did not have Selenium installed.

```
pip install Selenium
```